# How to deal with Context.Done(R value)

Tags: bots, botframework, chatbot

I have a msbot chat dialog that I want to have the following behaviour:

```
user -> get me some info about GARY
bot -> which gary, (prompt: choice options)
user -> gary peskett
bot -> sure, (hero card with gary's contact details)
```

I have this code

```
public class CustomerRepository
{
    private IList<Customer> _customerList = new List<Customer>
    {
        new Customer
        {
            Name = "Gary Peskett"
        },
        new Customer
        {
            Name = "Gary Richards"
        },
        new Customer
        {
            Name = "Barry White"
        }
    };

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetAll()
    {
        // usually calls a database (which is why async is on this method)
        return _customerList;
    }
}

public class XDialog : IDialog
{
    private readonly IIntent _intent;
    private readonly CustomerRepository _customerRepository;

    public XDialog(IIntent intent, CustomerRepository customerRepository)
    {
        // An intent is decided before this point
        _intent = intent;
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        // // An intent can provide parameters
        string name = _intent.Parameters["Name"] as string;
        IEnumerable<Customer> customers = await _customerRepository.GetAll();
        IList<Customer> limitedList = customers.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(name)).ToList();

        if (limitedList.Any())
        {
            if (limitedList.Count > 1)
            {
                PromptDialog.Choice(context, LimitListAgain, limitedList,
                    "Can you specify which customer you wanted?");
            }
            else
            {
                Customer customer = limitedList.FirstOrDefault();
                Finish(context, customer);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.Done("No customers have been found");
        }
    }

    private static async Task LimitListAgain(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Customer> result)
    {
        Customer customer = await result;
        Finish(context, customer);
    }

    private static void Finish(IDialogContext context, Customer customer)
    {
        HeroCard heroCard = new HeroCard
        {
            Title = customer?.Name
        };

        context.Done(heroCard);
    }
}
```

What i'm finding is that usually when I do context.Done(STRING) then that is output to the user, and this is really useful to end the dialog.  As I want to end with a hero card, its outputing the typename

```
Microsoft.Bot.Connector.HeroCard
```

Can anyone help by either explaining a better way to use context.Done(R value) or help me return a hero card to end the dialog?

The dialog is being called with

```
Chain.PostToChain()
    .Select(msg => Task.Run(() => _intentionService.Get(msg.ChannelId, msg.From.Id, msg.Text)).Result)
    .Select(intent => _actionDialogFactory.Create(intent)) // returns IDialog based on intent
    .Unwrap()
    .PostToUser();
```

Comment: This post https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs/Dialogs/HotelsDialog.cs shows that they return context.Done<object>(null);  I wonder if this is the best thing to do :s

Comment: Who is calling to XDialog?

Comment: Its being called from the Chain.PostToChain().  I've updated the question with the code I use

Comment: Right.. I see. I will post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is a side effect of using `Chain`.

As you may know, the `context.Done` doesn't post anything back to the user, it just ends the current dialog with the value provided.

The post to user is effectively happening in the `.PostToUser()` at the end of your `Chain`. Now, by looking into the [PostToUser's code](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/497252e8d9949be20baa2cebaa6ce56de04461cf/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/Chain.cs#L108), I realized that at the end of the game, it's doing a `context.PostAsync` of `item.ToString()`, being item the payload provided in the `context.Done` in this case. See [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/497252e8d9949be20baa2cebaa6ce56de04461cf/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/Chain.cs#L509).

One option (I haven't tested this), could be using `.Do` instead of `.PostToUser()` and manually perform what the [PostToUserDialog](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/497252e8d9949be20baa2cebaa6ce56de04461cf/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/Chain.cs#L495) does and finally perform a  context.PostAsync() by creating a new `IMessageActivity` and adding the `HeroCard` as an attachment.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Based on your answer i've decided to move away from Chaining the conversation.  I found this https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs/Dialogs/RootDialog.cs and i'm now using it to manage my dialog flow